# suds.client and import client what is "import client"

Tags: python-2.7, openstack

This part of code is to access openstack API using python. What import "Client" do?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import sys

from suds.client import Client

# Credentials
username = 'user05'
password = 'A99tYmkRV'
.
.
.
.
```

I wonder what Client is, and how to setup python to access Openstack based cloud? How connectivity proceeds? 
How can I setup "Client"?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Client-server technology, Client is an entity which requests some service/resource from server. Server is an entity which serves the request/resource. For Client to make request, it must specify server address as well as resource Identifier(URL).

The above analogy also applies to `Client` in suds.client package. For more information regarding, how to connect any server, refer to followng link :-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903250/how-to-extract-method-using-suds-in-python
```